# Assigning an image to the composite custom control c# VS .NET 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmapimage

The problem concerns Windows Forms.

I have no idea how to do it. I've tried following:

1) Add a Bitmap (*CarControl.bmp*) do the solution, then set *BuildAction* to *Embedded Resource* and add the ToolBoxBitmapAttribute like:

```
 [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(CarControl),"CarControl")]
```

2) Going into *Properties*, then in *Resources* section I've added some images. Still doesn't work.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming is very important, otherwise it does not work.

```
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(CarControl), "Resources.CarControl.png")]
```

[image: Properties]

**Another important note:**

If you open the solution of your `CarControl` you will always see the default gear icons for the controls of your actual build. But if you make a build and you add the controls of this (released) library to the Toolbox either by drag-and-dropping the dll or by *Right click/Choose Items...*, then the icon will appear.

If you did everything well, you will able to find the embedded resource in the compiled .dll when you open it with Reflector or other disassembler tool. The following example is from System.dll:
[image: Resources-decompiled]

You should find a `<DefaultNamespace of your project>.<Your resources folder>.CarControl.png` here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I must say though, that I can't see any Resources folder in my solution after I add images. I can just see images by opening Resources.resx file. How to load it from there?

Comment: Just create the folder manually. You can name it differently, but the path must be reflected in the attribute. Resources in Resources.resx work differently. The Build Action for images added to Resources.resx will be None and the .resx file itself will be embedded.

Comment: I understand it, but still have one more question, maybe two :)
If I particularly would like to get to the file from Resources.resx, isn't that possible? And if I create the folder Resources manually, would I be able to remove created folder from the disk and yet application will be still running? Cause this is my purpose, to load this image into assembly so I can use the image without having it on the disk.

Comment: No, it does not work wit the ToolboxBitmap attribute. I have just edited the answer to make it clear. The ToolboxBitmap can refer only a standalone resource as you can see in the screenshot.